# Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning. This declaration shadows an existing declaration

Tags: declaration

```
function Createvault(string memory name, address[] memory users, uint initialamount)public returns(uint vaultId){

    vault storage vault = vaults[totalvaults];
    vault.creator = msg.sender;
    vault.name = name;
    vault.amount = initialamount;

    totalvaults <=1;
    return totalvaults -1;
}
function addAmount(uint vaultId, uint amount)public {
    vault storage vault = vaults[vaultId];
    require(msg.sender == vault.creator,"not vault owner");
    vault.amount += amount;
}
function distribute( uint vaultId)public {
    vault storage vault = vaults[vaultId];
    uint amountperuser =vault.amount / vault.users.length;
    if(vault.amount !=0){
        for(uint i; i < vault.users.length;i++){
            vault.amount = amountperuser;
            balance[vault.users[i]] = amountperuser;
        }}
        else{
            revert ("no funds avelible");
        }
        emit vaultdistribution(vaultId,amountperuser*vault.users.length);  
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Warning 1**

I'm assuming your struct declaration is something like this:

```
struct vault {
    address creator;
    string name;
    uint amount;
}
```

`vault storage vault = vaults[vaultId];` this line gives you the warning because you're declaring the variable with the name `vault`, which is already used to declare the struct

Solution: Rename the Struct with the name `Vault` and you should get rid of the 1st warning. It is also a naming convention practice to name the Struct in the Pascal case.

**Warning 2**

In `Createvault(string memory name, address[] memory users, uint initialamount)` you're not using the value of `users` array anywhere in the function.

Solution: You can remove it from the parameters if it is not required to be used in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your vault variable--the variable should not have the same name as the struct type it is.

Comment: i will try this but it cannot be change in struct